# Propability of an event when this event happens the chance decreases but when it doesn't happen chance increases.

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithmic-game-theory

**A bit of story**

I've returned to Black Desert after a long time and now, as I've learned some math in my free time so... I'm wondering about some stuff from math point of view. Like how many Items and money (How much time) I have to waste to fully upgrade my gear.

There are websites that calculate this, but I'm more interested in math RN.

**To the problem.**

1. An item has a chance to be upgraded, the chance to upgrade to level 1 is 70%, level 2—60% level 3—40% and from now on each level up to level 10 will divide the chance by two rounded to 2 decimal places. What's middle amount of upgrades a player has to do to get fully upgraded item.

*My guess for this is*

Let's say that $P(i)={P(1)=0.7,...,P(10)=0.0031}, i \in [1,10]$ so we use binomial distribution $(B(i)=(_x^n){P(i)}^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ and find at what $n$(amount of tries) we have the highest $B(i)$ and sum that up

Roughly I got 634 using excel

<s>One more way to do this is use $1-(1-P(i))^n$ and find at what $n$ we have roughly 1 (same 4 digits after the comma) sum that up</s>

And I got 13688 which is a LOT bigger than 634.

EDIT: This is wrong, thanks to [David K](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/139123/david-k) we can say that this calculates amount of tries for probability to exceed 99.995

And one more way to do this is to find mathematical expectation which is roughly $M(i)=\frac{1}{P(i)}$ rounded down and summed up $\begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{1}{P(i)} \end{align*}$

This gives me 639 which looks a lot more truthful judging by first way.

2. An item has a chance to be upgraded, the chance to upgrade to level 1 is 70%, level 2—60% level 3—40% and from now on each level up to level 10 will divide the chance by two rounded to 2 decimal places. If upgrade failed, you lose 1 level. What's middle amount of upgrades a player has to do to get fully upgraded item.

Absolutely no Idea how to solve this.

**Questions**

Why 2 way of solving this gives me such an obscure answer, am I missing something?
Did I understand binomial distribution right?
Is there any other way to solve 1st one?
Is there a way to use BINOM.INV (EXCEL Function) to solve the 1st one? I personally think that with something like BINOM.INV(n;P(i);0,9999) is right, but I really don't know if this is right.
What about minimum and maximum amount of tries?
How to solve the second one?
What about minimum and maximum amount of tries? (not necessary, I'll probably understand it myself, but I already spent so much time at this I'm getting frustrated)

Comment: You get the result $13688$ by asking the question, "If I plan in advance to try $n$ times, what $n$ can I pick so that the probability to succeed is $99.995\%$ or better?" So you're not asking about the average now, you're asking for something that is an approximation of the maximum (to within four decimal places of probability). Almost all the time you will succeed in far fewer than $n$ tries, so the average number of tries will be a lot less than $13688.$

Comment: Thanks, I should have just written it as $1-q^n$ to understand that, but the site I used for research was weird.

Comment: Sorry but I have few questions, why integrational negative binomial distribution is equal to  $1-q^n$.  

As far as I understand $NBD(f,w,p) f-failure, w-win, p-probability$ gives a chance to get f-failures in a row then 1 win. So at 
$NBD(127,1,0.0031)$ I should get the chance to get 127 failures in a row and then 1 win, but the chance I get is 0,0021 which just looks like off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, note that if $T_i$ denotes the random time upgrade from level $i-1$ to $i$, then $T_i$ is a geometric random variable with success probability $p_i$. A geometric random variable counts the number of trials to the first success and the mean of a geometric random variable with success parameter $p$ is given by $1/p$. If we denote the total time to upgrade as $T$, then
\begin{align*}
T = \sum_{i = 1}^{10} T_i \implies \mathbb{E}[T] = \sum_{i = 1}^{10}\mathbb{E}[T_i] = \sum_{i = 1}^{10}\frac{1}{p_i},
\end{align*}
which is what you believed your answer to be.

For the second part, let $t_i$ denote the expected time upgrade to level $10$ starting from level $i$. Note that $t_i$'s satisfy the following relation for $i = 0, 1, 2, \dots, 9$:
\begin{align*}
t_i = p_i t_{i+1} + (1 - p_i)t_{i-1} + 1,
\end{align*}
with $t_{10} = 0$ and $t_{-1} = t_0$ (since you cannot go lower than $0$). You can solve this system of linear equations to obtain $t_0$, which is your required answer.

Comment: What about minimum and maximum tries? the $t_i=\frac{1}{P(i)}$?

Comment: Minimum and maximum tries in both the parts are $10$ and $\infty$ respectively.

Comment: Yeah, but this is highly unlikely, I mean… can we find within what limits the most probable amount of tries lies. [Excel table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ujMMbEtRFxRTOeCfQhO2SSxccsLcrB6SG5P0JB3513g/edit#gid=986536717), but now as I look at it the number of tries is probably within 634-639 Difference between Bernoulli which gives me first max value and the math expectation which gives me exact one.

Comment: Are you asking bounds of the form $\Pr(T > N) \leq \delta$ for some $\delta \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Probably yes, De Moivre–Laplace theorem seems to be that?

Comment: For the first part, you can refer to this paper, specifically Theorem 2.1: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.08157. I am not sure about second part, but literature on time to absorption in a Markov Chain is great point to begin with.